# changing the scale of a matplotlib plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a chart with background as a colormap in python. I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,50,0.01)
y = 1000*np.sin(x)
yarr = np.vstack((x,))
plt.imshow(yarr, extent=(min(x),max(x), min(y),max(y)), cmap=cm.hot)
plt.plot(x, y, color='cornflowerblue',lw=4)
```

However, this produces an image looking like:

[image]

Is there a way to make the graph look 'normal'? I.e. so that I can what is happening (making the axis area more 'square').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `plt.imshow()` expects "square" pixels, in order to preserve the aspect ratio of the image (see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)). Use the option `aspect='auto'` to get the desired result :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,50,0.01)
y = 1000*np.sin(x)
yarr = np.vstack((x,))
plt.imshow(yarr, extent=(min(x),max(x), min(y),max(y)), cmap=cm.hot, aspect="auto")
plt.plot(x, y, color='cornflowerblue',lw=4)
```

[image: Matplotlib igure]